# How to make correct encapsulation with multithreading .NET C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

As you can see, I have two classes. RfidReaderHardware generates event in thread "th", but Form running at another thread. As you can see, in form if use Invoke method of ListViewControl. So, question is how to change RfidReaderHardware to resolve encapsulation problem.

```
public class RfidReaderHardware : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler<RfidReaderEventArgs> OnNewPackage;
    Thread th;
    //This method will be called from thread "th"
    private void FireNewPackageEvent(UHFPackage package)
    {
        ... code ...
    }
    ... some code ...
}
```

and we have example code, where this event is using

```
public partial class PassageForm : Form
{
    RfidReaderHardware RfidReader = new RfidReaderHardware(...);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RfidReader.OnNewPackage += NewRfidPackage;
    }
    //not sure, but i think it's running in thread "th"
    private void NewRfidPackage(Object o, RfidReaderEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        //from point of encapsulation view it's wrong as you know
        CPackageList.Invoke(new Action(() => {CPackageList.Items.Add(item); }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so sure there's any real need to fix this, having the UI object itself deal with the fact that event is fired on the "wrong" thread is not a flaw.  As long as you know it is in fact fired on the wrong thread, a documentation requirement.

.NET however has a general mechanism to solve this, it is used in several places inside the .NET Framework code.  Your RfidReaderHardware class constructor can copy the value of [SynchronizationContext.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and store it in a field.  With the implicit assumption that the object is created by code that runs on the UI thread.  When you are ready to fire the event, and the copied object isn't null, you can then use its Post() or Send() method.  Which automagically makes the code resume on the UI thread.  Regardless of the specific UI class library that was used, works just as well in a WPF or Universal app for example.

Some sample code, it doesn't take much:

```
public class RfidReaderHardware {
    public event EventHandler Received;

    public RfidReaderHardware() {
        syncContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    protected void OnReceived(EventArgs e) {
        if (syncContext == null) FireReceived(e);
        else syncContext.Send((_) => FireReceived(e), null);
    }

    protected void FireReceived(EventArgs e) {
        var handler = Received;
        if (handler != null) Received(this, e);
    }

    private System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> question is how to change RfidReaderHardware to resolve encapsulation problem

In fact there is no encapsulation problem. By definition, the relation between event source and subscriber is one to many, hence the source cannot "encapsulate" a logic for a specific subscriber. It's the subscriber choice how to handle the notification. One can ignore it, or handle it immediately, or like in your case handle it on the UI thread either synchronously (using `Control.Invoke`) or asynchronously (using `Control.BeginInvoke`).

Comment: I think, developer shouldn't think how another class works. And it reason, why I make this thing. Strange definition you were found : ). I understand about one-to-many relation, but what difference?

Comment: @NikolayChernov I could have easily provided you what Hans posted, but it's wrong from OOP point of view because it breaks SR (single responsibility) principle. Which for event source is to raise event. So I stay on my answer.  Your question was about encapsulation principle, if you wanted just something that automatically dispatches events on another thread, you shouldn't formulate it this way.