# C# Adapt BeginInvoke in a Class Library

Tags: c#

First off, I'm not a professional programmer, just an engineer who likes programming - please bear with me if I'm not accurate or lack the knowledge.

I'm trying to port the functionality of a GUI in C# (which I did not write) into a class library (as a wrapper to be laters used with Matlab). The original code involves the use of "BeginInvoke", which as far as I understand is incompatible with class library.

**Is there a relatively easy way to adapt this code to work in class library?**
I would also appreciate some basic explanation, but don't get too technical on me, because I might not understand! :)

Example snippet:

```
//.... stuff happening during form load...

_devices.OnSearch = SearchDevicesEvent;

//... other stuff happening....

private void SearchDevicesEvent(object sender,
                                        ClassListOfDevices.EventSearchDevicesArg e)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new ClassListOfDevices.SearchDevicesEventHandler(UpdataSearchDevicesEvent),
                        new[] { sender, e });
        }
```

Comment: `BeginInvoke` needs a WinForms form or control to work.  What do you intend your class library to do?  Will it only do computations, or will it also need some UI?

Comment: The BeginInvoke it's to do something async? Wait for some result?

Comment: I want to get rid of the UI, but keep all functionalities, i.e. make the class's methods execute the same functions as the various controls.

Comment: You don't need Begininvoke if you are not using UI thread. Are you using just to update the UI working around error of different thread?

Comment: Does the code actually need to be run on the main thread? BeginInvoke makes the code/function be run on the UI thread(main thread) of the application.

Comment: I've added another snippet to demonstrate how the function with BeginInvoke is assigned to one of the objects in the code.

Comment: I just want to clarify that I didn't write the original GUI, and I don't know what its code 'wants' or 'needs'. I just want the all the original functionalities to be executed via class methods instead of callback to a button press.

Comment: If you will use with C# project, just create your class, add your functions and add a reference to your dll into your project. Add the namespace and use your class. It's very simple with C#

Comment: Do mean that I programmatically create an instance of the GUI and simulate button presses?

Comment: Create your DLL project. Namespace is: Test. Add some class like Calc with function Sum with 2 args. Create another project but using WinForm. On References (Visual Studio),click on right button of mouse, Add Reference and add your DLL project to references (you can add DLL directly or add the project inside your solution). Add a button inside your Form, add a click event and you can do: var calc = new Calc(); and use calc.Sum(0, 0); for example.

Comment: Basically nothing will change of your original code. You just need to encapsulate your functions inside buttons to functions into your new class.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I'm not trying to port my functions into the GUI. I'm trying to port the function of the GUI into my DLL.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood. Are you trying to port functions of GUI (like the action of button press)?. If your button do a calculate, you can port that calculate into DLL and use that inside button. BeginInvoke it's to run somecode into UI thread. You don't have a UI thread inside a library.  What functions you want to port?

Comment: Ideally, I want to copy all of the function and just replace all the lines that have BeginInvoke with something that can work in the context of a class library.

Comment: Show me some code will not run into library context, please. `new ClassListOfDevices.SearchDevicesEventHandler(UpdataSearchDevicesEvent),
                        new[] { sender, e })`I dont know what this code do.

Comment: Again, what's not working is the use of BeginInvoke. What can I write instead of BeginInvoke that will work the same?

Comment: It's not clear what you want exactly. BeginInvoke have a purpose. I think you are asking for async calls, so that might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33584317/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

in order to get rid of BeginInvoke and still maintain functionality as was intended in the original code, I had to rewrite this:

```
private void SearchDevicesEvent(object sender,
                                        ClassListOfDevices.EventSearchDevicesArg e)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new ClassListOfDevices.SearchDevicesEventHandler(UpdataSearchDevicesEvent),
                        new[] { sender, e });
        }
```

into this:

```
private void SearchDevicesEvent(object sender,
                                        ClassListOfDevices.EventSearchDevicesArg e)
        {
            UpdataSearchDevicesEvent(object sender,
                                        ClassListOfDevices.EventSearchDevicesArg e)
                { //do stuff.... }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I resolved it by sending a byRef parameter to the function with a form:

```
Public Sub MySub(ByRef frm As frmMain)

    frm.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf LoadNews))

End Sub

Public Shared Sub LoadNews()
    diagAct.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = continutHtml
End Sub
```

Hope it helps!